# Check that values of two input fields are the same

Tags: react-native

I am using React Native and have a form like this :

```
   <Form>
        <Text>Password</Text>
        <Label>
         New Password
        </Label>
        <Item regular >
          <Input />
        </Item>
        <Label style={styles.label}>
          Confirm
        </Label>
        <Item regular >
          <Input/>
        </Item>

      </Form>

    <Button title="Update" onPress={() =>? } ></Button>
```

I need to check that the values in the input fields are the same, and check some restrictions that can be done using regular expressions.

How do I pass the values in the input fields so that I check in the controller?
I have done this using Angular in the past only.
It's my first time using react native, any guidance of best practice to do is is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is so basic that I suggest you to read React docs on forms: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Tell me if you have problems still when you have read the docs and tried implement the solution yourself :)

Comment: Thank you. My issue is once I've set a this.state on the constructor, and password: '' ,newPassword:'' fields.
And then on the <Input value={this.state.password} >
Now that field password sets the state to the value it has.
And I don't understand how to further interact with it. The application also uses redux, so it's somewhat confused my limited understanding.

Comment: If you don't yet know how to do controlled inputs with React I suggest you to drop Redux from your application since Redux will make your app more complex.